# Was my path of statistical data analysis correct/logical?

Tags: regression, hypothesis-testing, correlation, descriptive-statistics

I analyse physicochemical data from the river and two rows of wells - one located closer and the other further from the river.

[image]

The study's main aim is to investigate the variability (or heterogeneity) in the contents of the different parameters at the water intake concerning distance from the river. My initial assumption is the hypothesis that, statistically, a more significant influence of the river on the first well row can be demonstrated (the water in row 1 is very similar to the water in the river in terms of analysed parameters content). I want to ask if the path of my analysis was correct, or perhaps I should not include all these things in the paper and if something is redundant or incorrect.

My data is in (mg/L). The number of samples (observations) regarding a given parameter in each group is uneven but quite close (assume 50 / 70 / 40). This is due to the different sampling frequencies in the river and wells (I work with archival data, so it was not up to me when it comes to sampling time) and the unequal number of wells in the two lanes.

In the order of conducting the methodology:

- First, I used descriptive statistics to summarise my data in relation to surface water and groundwater (means, medians, standard deviations, etc.).
- Using heat maps, I then presented Pearson's r Correlation Coefficient for pairs of measurements: a) river vs. each well, b) first vs. second row of wells, c) parameter vs. parameter in each well (e.g. correlation of chloride with sulphate in well X).
- I then (inspired by a suggestion received here) divided my data by the sampling location of the selected parameter (river, row 1, row 2) and for the groups thus prepared, I performed linear regression (ordinary least squares - OLS) to see if the sampling location affected the value of that sample. Location 0 was the river, and I obtained OLS results for the first and second well rows.
- Finally, I performed a series of statistical tests for the data groups divided by sampling location and sampling season (for each parameter tested). The tests I used in order -> Shapiro-Wilk and Levene, followed by Kruskal-Wallis one-way analysis of variance (with Dunn-Bonferroni post hoc for each pair - river vs row 1, river vs row 2, row 1 vs row 2) for groups statistically significant in the Levene test, and ANOVA (Tukey-Kramer post hoc) for groups not statistically significant in the Levene test.

Do you think such an analysis is viable for the requirements of a journal focused on earth sciences/hydrogeology?